# How to calculate $\delta(x^4-\alpha^4)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Does the following equality hold?
\begin{equation}
\delta(x^4-\alpha^4)=\frac{1}{4\vert \alpha \vert} \left[ \delta(x-\alpha)+ \delta(x+\alpha) + \delta(x+i\alpha) + \delta(x-i\alpha)\right].
\end{equation}

Comment: What is $\delta$? Dirac's delta?

Comment: Yep! Dirac's delta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\delta$ is the probability measure supported on the solution set to $x^4-a^4=0,$ then yes, the result has this support. The constant is $1/|a^3|$ and not $1/|a|$, though.

Comment: Moreover, I have aother quention:  does the following equality hold? $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\delta(x^4-\alpha^4)  dx =\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) \frac{1}{4\vert \alpha \vert} \left[ \delta(x-\alpha)+ \delta(x+\alpha) + \delta(x+i\alpha) + \delta(x-i\alpha)\right] dx.$$ Because, $x\in\mathbb{R},$ i am not very sure the above equality.

Answer (score 0):

You have 
$$\delta\left(f(x)\right)=\sum_{\xi\;\text{root of $f$}} \frac{\delta(x-\xi)}{|f'(\xi)|}. $$
Therefore what you say must be corrected into
$$ \delta(x^4-a^4)=\frac{1}{4|a^3|}\left(\delta(x-a)+\delta(x+a)+\delta(x-\mathrm ia)+\delta(x+\mathrm ia)\right).$$

As a corrolary you have, if $a$ is real
$$\int_{\mathbf R}f(x)\delta(x^4-a^4)\,\mathrm d x=\frac{f(a)+f(-a)}{4|a^3|}.$$